# Changing React Photoswipe Caption Styling

Tags: css, reactjs, photoswipe

I am using the React PhotoSwipe Library to set up a Lightbox. I am trying to change the default styling for the text caption of the React Photoswipe Item Component. In the dev tools, it says it is styled by a class called "pswp__default-caption" however it is nowhere to be found within the photoswipe.css file.

```css
.pswp {
  --pswp-bg: white;
  --pswp-placeholder-bg: #222;
  

  --pswp-root-z-index: 100000;
  
  --pswp-preloader-color: rgba(79, 79, 79, 0.4);
  --pswp-preloader-color-secondary: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  
  /* defined via js:
  --pswp-transition-duration: 333ms; */
  
  --pswp-icon-color: #fff;
  --pswp-icon-color-secondary: #4f4f4f;
  --pswp-icon-stroke-color: #4f4f4f;
  --pswp-icon-stroke-width: 2px;

  --pswp-error-text-color: var(--pswp-icon-color);
}


/*
    Styles for basic PhotoSwipe (pswp) functionality (sliding area, open/close transitions)
*/

.pswp {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: var(--pswp-root-z-index);
    display: none;
    touch-action: none;
  text-shadow: none;
    outline: 0;
    opacity: 0.003;
    contain: layout style size;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

/* Prevents focus outline on the root element,
  (it may be focused initially) */
.pswp:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.pswp * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pswp img {
  max-width: none;
}

.pswp--open {
    display: block;
}

.pswp,
.pswp__bg {
    transform: translateZ(0);
    will-change: opacity;
}

.pswp__bg {
  opacity: 0.005;
    background: var(--pswp-bg);
}

.pswp,
.pswp__scroll-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pswp__scroll-wrap,
.pswp__bg,
.pswp__container,
.pswp__item,
.pswp__content,
.pswp__img,
.pswp__zoom-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.pswp__img,
.pswp__zoom-wrap {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.pswp--click-to-zoom.pswp--zoom-allowed .pswp__img {
    cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
    cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
    cursor: zoom-in;
}

.pswp--click-to-zoom.pswp--zoomed-in .pswp__img {
    cursor: move;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: grab;
}

.pswp--click-to-zoom.pswp--zoomed-in .pswp__img:active {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}

/* :active to override grabbing cursor */
.pswp--no-mouse-drag.pswp--zoomed-in .pswp__img,
.pswp--no-mouse-drag.pswp--zoomed-in .pswp__img:active,
.pswp__img {
    cursor: -webkit-zoom-out;
    cursor: -moz-zoom-out;
    cursor: zoom-out;
}


/* Prevent selection and tap highlights */
.pswp__container,
.pswp__img,
.pswp__button,
.pswp__counter {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.pswp__item {
    /* z-index for fade transition */
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pswp__hidden {
    display: none !important;
}

/* Allow to click through pswp__content element, but not its children */
.pswp__content {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.pswp__content > * {
  pointer-events: auto;
}


/*

  PhotoSwipe UI

*/

/*
    Error message appears when image is not loaded
    (JS option errorMsg controls markup)
*/
.pswp__error-msg-container {
  display: grid;
}
.pswp__error-msg {
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1;
    color: var(--pswp-error-text-color);
}

/*
class pswp__hide-on-close is applied to elements that
should hide (for example fade out) when PhotoSwipe is closed
and show (for example fade in) when PhotoSwipe is opened
 */
.pswp .pswp__hide-on-close {
    opacity: 0.005;
    will-change: opacity;
    transition: opacity var(--pswp-transition-duration) cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.22, 1);
    z-index: 10; /* always overlap slide content */
    pointer-events: none; /* hidden elements should not be clickable */
}

/* class pswp--ui-visible is added when opening or closing transition starts */
.pswp--ui-visible .pswp__hide-on-close {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

/* <button> styles, including css reset */
.pswp__button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    opacity: 0.85;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.pswp__button:hover,
.pswp__button:active,
.pswp__button:focus {
  transition: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

.pswp__button:disabled {
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: auto;
}

.pswp__icn {
  fill: var(--pswp-icon-color);
  color: var(--pswp-icon-color-secondary);
}

.pswp__icn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.pswp__icn-shadow {
  stroke: var(--pswp-icon-stroke-color);
  stroke-width: var(--pswp-icon-stroke-width);
  fill: none;
}

.pswp__icn:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/*
    div element that matches size of large image,
    large image loads on top of it,
    used when msrc is not provided
*/
div.pswp__img--placeholder,
.pswp__img--with-bg {
    background: var(--pswp-placeholder-bg);
}

.pswp__top-bar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
    z-index: 10;

    /* allow events to pass through top bar itself */
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
.pswp__top-bar > * {
  pointer-events: auto;
  /* this makes transition significantly more smooth,
     even though inner elements are not animated */
  will-change: opacity;
}


/*

  Close button

*/
.pswp__button--close {
  margin-right: 6px;
}


/*

  Arrow buttons

*/
.pswp__button--arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.pswp__button--arrow:disabled {
  display: none;
  cursor: default;
}

.pswp__button--arrow .pswp__icn {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -30px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.pswp--one-slide .pswp__button--arrow {
  display: none;
}

/* hide arrows on touch screens */
.pswp--touch .pswp__button--arrow {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* show arrows only after mouse was used */
.pswp--has_mouse .pswp__button--arrow {
  visibility: visible;
}

.pswp__button--arrow--prev {
  right: auto;
  left: 0px;
}

.pswp__button--arrow--next {
  right: 0px;
}
.pswp__button--arrow--next .pswp__icn {
  left: auto;
  right: 14px;
  /* flip horizontally */
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}

/*

  Zoom button

*/
.pswp__button--zoom {
  display: none;
}

.pswp--zoom-allowed .pswp__button--zoom {
  display: block;
}

/* "+" => "-" */
.pswp--zoomed-in .pswp__zoom-icn-bar-v {
  display: none;
}


/*

  Loading indicator

*/
.pswp__preloader {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.pswp__preloader .pswp__icn {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  animation: pswp-clockwise 600ms linear infinite;
}

.pswp__preloader--active .pswp__icn {
  opacity: 0.85;
}

@keyframes pswp-clockwise {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}


/*

  "1 of 10" counter

*/
.pswp__counter {
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-inline-start: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: var(--pswp-icon-color);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px var(--pswp-icon-color-secondary);
  opacity: 0.85;
}

.pswp--one-slide .pswp__counter {
  display: none;
}
```

I'm 100% certain it is the file responsible for styling the caption because the styling is removed if the file is removed, but I cannot find the "pswp__default-caption" class anywhere. Is there something I am missing or unaware of?